# How do I use nginx to serve one page?

Tags: nginx

nginx is running on my server because of an owncloud install I did a long time ago. How do I use the already running nginx instance to serve a single static page?

My actual use case:

I've got an automated backup script that deposits a timestamp of the last successful backup in a text file.  I'd like to be able to access that text file by visiting `http://myhomeip:12345/last_backup`

Answer (score 0):

Create file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myserver.conf`:

```
server { 
  listen 12345;
  server_name myhomeip;
  location /last_backup {
    alias /var/www/backups/last_backup.tar.gz ;
  }
  location / {
    deny all;
  }
}
```

and restart nginx.

Comment: It would be more helpful fot the OP and further visitors if you add some explanations to your answer.